# Sidekiq failed jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, sidekiq

I've set up Sidekiq to monitor some asynchronous and scheduled tasks.

When I queue a job I can see it on the web monitoring tool.

Here is an example of a job

```
class HardWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(name, count)
    raise "Error"
  end
end
```

If I then run `HardWorker.perform_in(10.second,'bob', 5)` and the job fails (which it always does intentionally), it seems to disappear from the web GUI. 'Failed', 'retries', 'processed' etc don't go up. None of the graphs change.

Here is what the log spits out:

`2015-04-19T11:03:40.013Z 1438 TID-3fk WARN: uninitialized constant HardWorker`

This makes sense as I created the class through console rather than in my project but shouldn't sidekiq show this as a failed job?

I've also tried force setting the following:

`sidekiq_options :retry => false`

`sidekiq_options :failures => true`

Anyone got any suggestions how to get the web app to show those failed jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out because I wrote the class in rails c the subsequent threads didn't know about the class. This was intentional but I didn't think about the fact that within the class it's involving Sidekiq meaning in my scenarios when it failed, it never spoke to Sidekiq reporting the failure.